# Adding Buttons to expendableListView as last Child

Tags: android, button, expandablelistview

I need help on the following question:

Is there a way to add a button as last child in an 'expendableListView' ?

[image]

The button should be below the "Short Text" field.

If you need any further information, please leave a comment, and I will provide them.

Comment: You have already a list of textviews for each group and you need to have at the bottom of below each list a button?

Comment: yes, exactly. And the number of `Textview elements` is variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ExpandableListView` should be backed by some data model. In each list item row you will have a text displayed in a View (TextView or Button). So first of all make yourself a class that holds this info:

```
public class RowData {
    public static final int TYPE_TEXT = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_BUTTON = 1;
    private String label;
    private int type;

    public RowData(String label, int type) {
        this.label = label;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public RowData(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

The easiest model (since we don't have an understanding of your code) would be a `LinkedHashMap<String, List<RowData>>`. The keys refer to group data ("00010", "00020", "00030", etc), while each value attached to these keys refers to group children (Ex. for "00010", you will have ["Material Group: No Information Found", etc]). Now, in your activity keep a reference to this data model:

```
private Map<String, List<RowData>> myData = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<RowData>>();
```

You need to keep a reference to ExpandableListView's adapter:

```
private BaseExpandableListAdapter adapter = new CustomSpecificAdapter(yourActivityContext, myData);
```

When you need to add that extra field you'll just add it to data model object:

```
myData.get("00010").add(new RowData("Button value", RowData.TYPE_BUTTON));
```

or for a `TextView`:
    myData.get("00010").add(new RowData("TextView value"));
and notify the adapter:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That will update the expandable list. However, you need to specify for each row what kind of views you will have, what type you will have for each position as this is very relevant for views recycling. So your relevant `CustomSpecificAdapter` methods could look something like: `public class CustomSpecificAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter`

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, List<RowData>> modelData;
private Context context;

public CustomSpecificAdapter(Context context, LinkedHashMap<String, List<RowData>> modelData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.modelData = modelData;
}

private RowData getMyDataObj(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    /**
     * safe to do this since we are using a LinkedHashMap
     * */
    List<List<RowData>> children = new ArrayList<List<RowData>>(modelData.values());
    return children.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return getMyDataObj(groupPosition, childPosition);
}

@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
    /**
     * since you will have a button and a textview there will be 2 types of views
     * */
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    RowData data = getMyDataObj(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (data.getType() == RowData.TYPE_TEXT) {
        return 0;
    }
    // for button
    return 1;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    /**
     * this is the intersting part
     * */
    RowData data = getMyDataObj(groupPosition, childPosition);
    TextView myTv = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        if(data.getType() == RowData.TYPE_BUTTON) {
            convertView = // inflate from button layout, in fact it's best to have only a <Button ... /> in the XML layout
        } else {
            convertView = // inflate from TextView layout, in fact it's best to have only a <Button ... /> in the XML layout
        }
    } 
    /**
     * Have the same id for both TextView and Button - Button extends from TextView and so setText() method is available through polimorphysm. Also no need for ViewHolder as getViewById() will refer to itself.
     * */
    myTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(the_same_id_in_both_xml_files);
    myTv.setText(data.getLabel());
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the effort, I still get some errors, but I get the basics. But why does `myTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(textView1);` not find my view?

Comment: You need to post the XML layout for both types of layouts. It should be there.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to add a button as last child in an
>   'expendableListView' ?

I believe yes, you should inflate another view (the view containing the buttons) for the last child in  your required group.

Something like this:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if (convertView == null) {
       if(groupPosition == FIRST_GROUP_POSITION && isLasChild){
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout_with_buttons, null);            
       }else{
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.normal_child_layout, null);
       }
   }
   //....
}
```

Comment: Okay, it works so far, I get a button as the last child of the first group. But I want a button as every last child, of every group (so I just used `if (isLastChild) {//button... else { //text` . But the button is now the second last in the second group, and the third last ind the third group and so on. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Nope, sorry, have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to implement your own `ExpandableListAdapter`, and implement the `getChildView` to control the view of each child row. Try this:

```
@Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if(view == null){

                if(isLastChild){
                    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_with_button, null);
                }else{
                    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                }
            }
            return view;
        }
```

Hope this helps.